# Does elementaryOS works with hybrid graphics?

Tags: graphics

I have an Ideapad320 with i5 8th gen + Geforce MX150 and I wanna know if elementaryOS runs in this hardware.

Comment: To eliminate any guesswork, I'd suggest creating a Live elementary OS USB flash drive and booting from it before actually installing the system: https://www.lifewire.com/create-elementary-os-live-usb-drive-2202054

Answer (score 0):

YES, the Linux kernel and elementary OS supports hybrid graphics technologies.

For your specific model you may get a black screen when you boot after installing elementary. If that happens you'd need to add `nomodeset` to the boot options on the grub menu. You do this by pressing e on the grub menu and then adding `nomodeset` in between `quiet splash`, like `quiet nomodeset splash`.

Then you'd need to install the nvidia driver from the terminal with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Or you could also install them from AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if the switchable graphics capabilities will work? If this is what you want to know, I suggest booting from USB as others have suggested, then open up a terminal execute `xrandr --listproviders`this should list both of your graphics devices. To learn how to enable the switchable graphics for certain program, I suggest [watching this video, it's a very clear explanation of how to do it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-ckiKQotNw)